# How to insert noise to a signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a signal with noise. I found this coding but I don't know how it works. Can somebody explain this to me?

```
x= cos(2*pi*12*[0:0.001:1.23]);
x(end) = [];
[b a] = butter(2,[0.6 0.7],'bandpass');
filtered_noise = filter(b,a,randn(1, length(x)*2));
x = (x + 0.5*filtered_noise(500:500+length(x)-1))/length(x)*2;
```

This is the result when I plot the x.

[image: Cosine signal with noise]

Comment: This code is creating random noise using a butterworth filter and you add that to your original signal, creating a noisy sine-wave

Answer (score 0):

The noise generation algorithm here is encoded in this line:

```
filtered_noise = filter(b,a,randn(1, length(x)*2));
```

Here the butterworth filter is applied to the random noise signal `randn(1, length(x)*2)` via the coefficients `a`, `b`. The noise signal is an array of `2460 = 1230*2` random elements between `0.0` and `1.0`. The filter is probably applied to ensure that the noise profile matches whatever the actual profile of the system being modeled is.

The next line takes `1230` elements from the noise profile starting at element `500`:

```
x = (x + 0.5*filtered_noise(500:500+length(x)-1))/length(x)*2;
```

There does not appear to be any reason to extract the noise from that particular index vs. any other. The magnitude of the final result is normalized by a factor of `1/615`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I'm not mistaken, the general equation for sinusoidal signal is 2*pi*f*t, so the frequency of the signal is 12 Hz. Am I right? And from the code, can I get the information about the noise? What is the frequency of the noise?

Comment: The frequency of the noise is random, but attenuated at higher frequencies by the butterworth filter.

Comment: You can get the frequency profile by doing something along the lines of `fft(0.5 * filtered_noise(500:500+length(x)-1)) / length(x) * 2`